# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac Flutter VS

Tags: flutter, visual-studio

The project folder is perfect. The error is in visual studio,flutter files or something.

I know there are old versions of VisualStudio and Flutter but my project was working perfectly in these versions. The errors appeared with a wrong update of visual studio, I downgraded it to the version I used to use but the errors persisted

Error Description:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.21.0].
> Required by:
> project :app > io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.21.0
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        14,1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Flutter Doctor:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.19043.1645], locale es-AR)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the build.gradle file as below

**Before**

```
 repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
 }
```

**After**

```
 repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
 }
```

Good luck.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).